# trying to add a list to a database, is there a better way?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, reddit

```
link_title = []
comments = []
username = request.form['user']
user = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/user/{username}/comments.json?'.format(username=username))
j = json.loads(user.content)
for i in j['data']['children']:
        link_title.append(i['data']['link_title'])
for i in j['data']['children']:
        comments.append(i['data']['body'])

g.db.execute("UPDATE comments SET (user,title,comments) VALUES (?,?,?)", (request.form['user'],  link_title, comments))
```

basically there is a form on my app, you enter a user, it runs this code I just showed. This will grab the comments/title/body from a user. I want to add the comments into 1 column, as a whole list, so that each time someone uses the form the comments will be erased. When I run this code, it says error at ( syntax, and points to my g.d.execute line. Am I approaching this wrong? how do I add the list to 1 column 1 row

EDIT:

```
cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE user(user_id integer primary key, username text)')
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE comments(comment_id integer primary key, title text, comments text, user_id, \
                        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id))')
```

when I insert into or delete anything in either user/comments table, I can see no constraints in place. I can add a user_id into the comments table even if no user exists. Is my code/logic incorrect?

Comment: Yes, by storing list items in a separate table with a foreign key. You may want to read up on database normalisation before continuing. :-)

Comment: I sort of understand your comment now, I need a main table to keep all the data, and a second table to keep the array, and link it to the first table. Ill google a bit more but it would save me a headache if I knew what I put in the first table and the linking table

Comment: That is what a foreign key is for; a row id in one table is used in another table to 'link back' to that one row.

Comment: But database design can fill a whole book, too much to expand on in comments.

Comment: I came up with something that I feel is right, but doesnt work, can you take a look at my edit